# Weird "zero ticks" on matplotlib subplot y-axis

Tags: matplotlib

I'm creating a plot consisting of several subplots in matplotlib, like this one:
[image: See my plot]

But for some reason, I get weird Zeros on the y-axis (actually on both sides of the plot): 
They don't seem to be ticks, since the `ax1.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])` statement does not affect them.

**Any ideas why I get these and how I can get rid of them?**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

subplots_adjust(hspace=0.000)

groups = ['01', '03', '05', '07']

for i in range(len(groups)):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,400)
    y = np.sin(x**2)

    ax1 = subplot(len(groups),1,i+1) 
    ax1.scatter(x, y, s=20, c='b', marker='o')
    plt.xlim(xmin=0,xmax=1)
    ax1.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just leftovers from the `x` ticks at `0.0` and `1.0`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from pylab import *   # don't do it, btw
import numpy as np


groups = ['01' , '03', '05', '07']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = []
for i in range(len(groups)):
  ax.append( fig.add_subplot( len(groups), 1, i+1 ) )

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.000)


for i in range(len(groups)):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi,400)
    y = np.sin(x**2)

    ax[i] = plt.subplot(len(groups),1,i+1) 
    ax[i].scatter(x, y, s=20, c='b', marker='o')
    ax[i].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    ax[i].set_xlim([0.001,0.9999])     # <<<<========== here


plt.show()
```

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks! (I ended up setting them to [-0.1,1.1] so I don't lose points directly at 0 or 1, but this pointed me the right way.)